# Articles for developing a GUI library

Tags: c++, c, user-interface

Basically, I'm unable to find any good articles for developing your own GUI, **that deal with good practices, the basic structure, event bubbling, tips and avoiding all the usual pitfalls**. I'm specifically not interested on how to build some proof-of-concept GUI in 5 minutes that just barely works... nor am I interested in building the next future GUI.

The purpose is to build a reasonably capable GUI to be used for tools for a game, however they will exist within the game itself so I don't want to use existing large scale GUIs, and I find most game GUIs to be rather bloated for what I need. And I enjoy the experience of doing it myself.

I have done a GUI in the past which worked very well to a point, however, due to some bad design decisions and inexperience it could only do so much (and was built in Flash so it got a lot of stuff for free). So I would like to really understand the basics this time.

Answer (score 1):

A few tips -

1) Pick your style the UI will work - will it be stateless? If yes, how are you going to handle the events appropriately? In case it'll be stateless, you'll maybe have to re-evaluate your UI user code twice in order to get up to date event changes from user side. If your UIs store state, then you won't have to care about handling events, but it'll limit your UIs when it comes to rapid mutations and rebuilds.

2) Do not rely on the OO too much, virtual methods are not the fastest thing in the world so use them with care; having some sort of inheritance based structure might help though. Beware of dynamic_cast and RTTI if you use objects; they will slow you down. Instead, set up an enum, get_type() method for every widget class, and do manual checks for castability.

3) Try to separate the looks and the UI logic/layout.

4) If you want dynamic windows, layouts etc. then you'll have to handle aligning, clamping, positions etc. and their updates. If you want just statically positioned widgets, it'll make it much easier.

5) Do not overdesign, you won't benefit from that.

There is not really anything too specific I tell you; having some concrete question would help, maybe?

Comment: Thanks! This will be implemented in Lua, and the idea is to make it retained, immediate mode seems great for "flatter" and simpler GUIs. What I'm looking for is mostly just, what should the basics look like? How to do event propagation right (mouse clicks, input focus, etc), recommended base class methods, how to deal with children and positioning (like labels in a button) and things like that.

Comment: I think looking at the UI code in the Cube 2 game engine might be useful. It's not exactly nice code, but it implements pretty elegant stateless UIs with minimal amount of code, basically no OO, just using a proxy and double reevaluation (there is not much you can do about that when going stateless). Stateless is a nice idea definitely. But the reevaluation and rebuilds of UIs per-frame do not exactly make up for big performance, so for complicated UI structures, you're better off with state-based system.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the docs for existing GUI libraries. That should give you details on proven designs to handle the issues you've run into.

You might want to start with one you're familiar with, but one that I think is designed quite well is [AppKit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_Kit). Its API is Obj-C so it would require some adjustment if you wanted to copy it, but the docs give all kinds of details about how objects interact to, e.g. handle events, and how layout constraints work, which should be directly applicable to designing an OO GUI in most any language.

Comment: Yeah, I am looking at some existing GUI libraries, but really, unless you are already familiar with them, it's quite a complex task to really understand how they work at such a low-level. Currently looking at GWEN which is kind of what I'm after, but still it's not entirely easy to get a grip of what's going on.